# How I can add platform collision?

Tags: python, game-development, platform

I'm newbe in programming and I'm still learn and i try make my first platform game.
In first steps everything was good but i have problem with detect collision with platform.
I add collision if player is falling and it work good, but if I try add collision with bottom, left and right side platform, is not working good :(

I add all code to cleary view. If player is falling, code work okay.

Do You have idea what I can do, to add collisions?

```
#main

# Project 1 - platform game

import pygame as pg 
import random
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from os import path

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # inicjalizacja okna gry itd
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.running = True 
        self.font_name = pg.font.match_font(FONT_NAME) # fonts
        
    def new(self):
        # start a new game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()    # all sprite's
        self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self)  # dodaję gracza
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)   
        # dodaję platformy
        for plat in PLATFORM_LIST:
            p = Platform(*plat)
            self.all_sprites.add(p)
            self.platforms.add(p)
            
        #ground generator  
        i = 0
        x = 0
        while i < 35:
            ground = Platform(x, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40)
            self.all_sprites.add(ground)
            self.platforms.add(ground)
            i += 1
            x += 50
        
            
        
        
        self.run() # game loop start
    
    def run(self):
        # game loop
        self.playing = True 
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()   
            self.update()   
            self.draw()     
            
    def update(self):
        # game loop udpate
        self.all_sprites.update()
        # collision if player is falling
        if self.player.vel.y > 0:
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
            if hits:
                self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
                self.player.vel.y = 0   
                
                # still I don't have idea what I can make collision with right, left and bottom 
                  platform
        
                
                
                
        # if player reach 1/2 screen
        if self.player.rect.right >= WIDTH / 2: 
            self.player.pos.x -= abs(self.player.vel.x)
            for plat in self.platforms:
                plat.rect.right -= abs(self.player.vel.x)  
                if plat.rect.right <= WIDTH:    
                    plat.kill                   
                    
        # player die
        if self.player.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
            self.playing = False
                    
        
    def events(self):
        # game loop - events
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.jump()
        
    def draw(self):
        #game loop - draw
        self.screen.fill(BLACK) 
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen) 
        
        pg.display.flip()  
        
    def show_start_screen(self):
        # start screen not add yet
        pass
        
    def show_go_screen(self):
        # game over screen
        if not self.running:
            return
        self.screen.fill(BLUE)
        self.draw_text("GAME OVER!", 48, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 4)
        self.draw_text("Press button to play again", 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 3 / 4)
        pg.display.flip()
        self.wait_for_key()
            
    def wait_for_key(self):
        waiting = True
        while waiting:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    waiting = False
                    self.running = False
                if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                    waiting = False
                    
    def draw_text(self, text, size, color, x, y):
        font = pg.font.Font(self.font_name, size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
        self.screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
            
        
    
g = Game()      
g.show_start_screen() 
while g.running:    
    g.new()     
    g.show_go_screen()   
    
pg.quit()

#SPRITES

import pygame as pg
from settings import *
import random
vec = pg.math.Vector2 


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 40))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)  
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)    
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)   
        
    def jump(self):
        
        self.rect.x += 1
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
        self.rect.x -= 1
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = - PLAYER_JUMP
        
    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)  # PLAYER_GRAV - gravity
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = - PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC
        
        
        # add friction
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION 
        # równanie ruchu
        self.vel += self.acc
        if abs(self.vel.x) < 0.1:
            self.vel.x = 0
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc 
        if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
            self.pos.x = WIDTH
        if self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = 0
        
        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos 
        
class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    


    # settings

TITLE = "Project One"
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60
FONT_NAME = 'comic sans ms'  # arial, verdana, times new roman, palatino, garamond, comic sans ms

# ustawienia gracza
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_JUMP = 20
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.8

# lista platform

GROUND_LIST =[(0, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40),
              (50, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40),
              (100, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40),
              (150, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40),
              (200, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40),
              (250, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40),
              (300, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40),
              (350, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40),
              (400, HEIGHT - 40, 50, 40)]

PLATFORM_LIST = [(300, 300, 75, 40),
                (400, 350, 75, 40),
                (600, 300, 75, 40),
                (800, 250, 75, 40),
                (1000, 350, 75, 40),
                (1200, 400, 75, 40),
                (1400, 200, 75, 40),]


# defined colors

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
```

Comment: For horizontal and vertical collision see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collision-detection-in-pygame/

Answer (score 1):

I write again,
I did some work and found a solution to my problem :) I had to describe the collisions for x and y separately. Additionally, entering the collisions inside the Player class helped to eliminate the problem with the player jumping to the top platforms.